# method post failed to load resource the server responded with a status 404

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Im new in Springboot, so im getting this error

> POST http://localhost:63342/insacol/static/api/users 404 (Not Found). registerUser.js:20
> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

js code:

```
// Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
$(document).ready(function() {

});


  async function registerUser(){
      let dates ={};
      dates.name = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
      dates.lastname = document.getElementById('txtLastName').value;
      dates.email = document.getElementById('txtEmail').value;
      dates.password = document.getElementById('txtPassword').value;
      let repeatPassword = document.getElementById('txtRepeatPassword').value;

      if (repeatPassword != dates.password){
          alert('La contraseña es diferente');
          return;
      }
    console.log(dates);
    const request = await fetch('api/users', { method: 'POST', headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    body: JSON.stringify(dates)
    const users = await request.json()
  }
```

java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void insertUser(@RequestBody User user){
        userDao.insertar(user);
    }
```

html code:

```
<a onclick="registerUser()" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Register Usuario</a>
```

Comment: is that path defined in your spring boot. from the code example you shared its hard to tell. It would be better if you were to share a runnable example.

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(JSON.stringify(dates)`? Is the format correct?
And are you sure the URL you are calling is the correct one? Through which port is Spring boot running? Since  `63342` seems a bit unusual to me

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void insertUser(@RequestBody User user){
    userDao.insertar(user);
}
```

with this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "insacol/static/api/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void insertUser(@RequestBody User user){
    userDao.insertar(user);
}
```

The problem should be related to the URL you invoke;